# Warning in Project of XCFramework: Module 'ModuleName' was not compiled with library evolution support

Tags: xcode11.3, xcframework

I'm trying to create XCFramework, which has inside several dependencies imported with SPM. I set `BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISRTIBUTION` to YES for target.

But this warning inside of XCFramework Project next each line `import <ModuleName>` makes me curious: is there something wrong there?

Warning:

```
Module 'ModuleName' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for 'XCFrameworkName' can't be guaranteed
```

Note: Archiving and creating xcframework succeeded.

Comment: FWIW, to explain the warning message, `XCFramework` is linking to `ModuleName` but `ModuleName` isn't exporting the .interface linker file that is needed to guarantee ABI compat (because it doesn't have BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION set). The risks of doing that are unclear to me though, I am looking for that information still. My question is, is there a risk that the library will link and potentially crash at runtime due to ABI incompat?

Comment: Did you solved that?

Comment: hi @tdtkien, my temporary solution was using source code of framework-project instead of frameworks.

Comment: I couldn't solve that but new binary has been accepted by Apple yesterday. So I think this is not really a serious bug